# Select multiple elements with same class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, class, select

I use jQuery UI dialog plugin to show a confirmation box for deleting the respective `span`  like this. Here's my JS code :

```
 $("#dialog-stergelu").dialog({ 
        autoOpen: false, 
        bgiframe: true, 
        resizable: false, 
        width: 400, 
        modal: true, 
        overlay: { 
            backgroundColor: '#000', 
            opacity: 0.5 
        }, 
        buttons: { 
            'Sterge': function() { 
                     window.location = $('.opener').attr('confirm');
             }, 
             'Anuleaza': function() { 
                      $(this).dialog('close'); 
              } 
         } 
  }); 
  $('.opener').click(function() { 
         $('#dialog-stergelu').dialog('open'); 
  });
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="dialog-stergelu" title="Stergeti acest raport ? ">
   <p>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"> </span>Chiar doriti sa stergeti acesta lucrare ? (Apasati "Anuleaza" pentru anularea comenzi)
   </p>
</div>
<span class="opener" confirm="delete.php?id=213115">Delete</span>
<span class="opener" confirm="delete.php?id=22314">Delete</span>
<span class="opener" confirm="delete.php?id=222111">Delete</span>
<span class="opener" confirm="delete.php?id=215231">Delete</span>
<span class="opener" confirm="delete.php?id=223151">Delete</span>
```

I want to get attr `confirm` from the clicked `span`. Right now it's getting only the first one.

Comment: @passionateCoder - The question _is_ in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try storing the url in `data` of `$("#dialog-stergelu")` element like this and then open it. Like this  :

```
$('.opener').click(function() { 
    var url= $(this).attr("confirm"); //really, why wont this work?
    $('#dialog-stergelu').data('url', url).dialog('open'); 
});
```

Then, in your dialog's `buttons` option,

```
buttons: { 
    'Sterge': function() { 
        window.location = $(this).data("url");
    }, 
    'Anuleaza': function() { 
        $(this).dialog('close'); 
    } 
}
```

Here's a working demo : http://jsbin.com/edudun/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line:

```
window.location = $(this).attr('confirm');
```

with this:

```
window.location = $('.opener').attr('confirm');
```

Answer (score 0):

After window.location is set, the browser changes the url and scripts on the page will stop executing.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is that you want to get the `span` that was clicked yes? Instead of incorrectly selecting first one matched by `$('.opener')` yes?

You need to modify your click callback to:

```
$('.opener').click(function(e) {  
    // jqEl is your specfic jQuery span.opener that was clicked.
    // You can pass it to the dialog using any number of methods.
    var jqEl = $(e.target); 

    ('#dialog-stergelu').dialog('open'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code...

$("#dialog-stergelu").dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false, 
    bgiframe: true, 
    resizable: false, 
    width: 400, 
    modal: true, 
    overlay: { 
        backgroundColor: '#000', 
        opacity: 0.5 
    }, 
    buttons: { 
        'Sterge': function() { 
            window.location = $('#dialog-stergelu').data('confirm');
         }, 
         'Anuleaza': function() { 
             $(this).dialog('close'); 
         } 
    } 
}); 
$('.opener').click(function() { 
    $('#dialog-stergelu').data('confirm',$(this).attr('confirm'));
    $('#dialog-stergelu').dialog('open'); 
});
```